# I tried to append my own data to a submitted form via ajax but the submit isn't going through

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I dynamically created a survey form using jquery and I want to submit the form via ajax and append my own data to it. I'm doing that because the created survey has questions in it and each question has a certain number of answers. But if you just submit the form you get an array of questions and an array of answers but there is no way to tell which answer belongs to which question. To deal with this problem, I've tried to create my own array, or rather a map where the questions are the keys and each question has its own answers as values. I didn't find a better way to accomplish that as to just use ajax to change the submit. As the title suggests, that didn't work, it just doesn't go through, there are no error messages.

```
$('.survey').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var map = new Array();
    var q;
    var form = $(this);
    $('div[name="question"]').each(function(){
        q = $(this).find('.question')[0].value;
        map["q"] = new Array();
        $(this).find('.answer').each(function(){
            map["q"].push($(this).val()+"");
        });
    });
    var data = form.serializeArray();
    data["questions"] = JSON.stringify(map);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: data
        });
});
```

Thats the code in question that doesn't work and here is the jsfiddle for the whole program: https://jsfiddle.net/e9tbcwdj

Everything works fine except the submit. When I dont stringify my map I can see via alert that map got successfully appended to data and that data["questions"]["q"][0], for example, shows the expected result. Thats why I'm pretty sure the problem is the serialization, but I'm not really sure how to serialize my "map" since stringify didn't do the job. I'm always a little helpless when it comes to serialization. Should I maybe use the map function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sayalok for all the trouble you've went through because of me, but I've got my problem now: My code works fine. I put a var_dump on the php page I was posting to, but because I used ajax and never changed pages, just posted to the php page, I never saw the var_dump and therefore thought, the submit didn't go through. Still, thank you for your help.

Comment: u r welcome. its pleasure to help each other here and also great fun

Answer (score 0):

except using a class use id in ur form

```
      var form = $('#surveyForm');
```

in ur html form add this id

```
      <form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>start" class="survey" id="surveyForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
        <input type="button" class="addQst" value="Add question">
        <input type="submit" class="submitForm" value="Generate">
      </form>
```

And give a name to ur question and answer input

```
      var question = $('<input type="text" class="question" name="quest">');
      var answer = $('<input type="text" class="answer" name="answr">');
```

Full Code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.survey').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var map = new Array();
            var q;
            var form = $('#surveyForm');
            $('div[name="question"]').each(function(){
                q = $(this).find('.question')[0].value;
                map["q"] = new Array();
                $(this).find('.answer').each(function(){
                    map["q"].push($(this).val()+"");
                });
            });
            var data = form.serializeArray();
            console.log(data)
            data["questions"] = JSON.stringify(map);
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: data
            });
        });
        $('.addQst').click(function () {
            var wrapperQuestion = $('<div name="question">');
            var removeQuestion = $('<input type="button" class="rmvQst" value="Delete">');
            var question = $('<input type="text" class="question" name="quest">');
            var addAnswer =$('<input type="button" class="addAsw" value="Add answer">');
            addAnswer.click(function() {
                var wrapperAnswer = $('<div>');
                var answer = $('<input type="text" class="answer" name="answr">');
                var removeAnswer = $('<input type="button" class="rmvAsw" value="Delete">');
                removeAnswer.click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
                wrapperAnswer.append(answer);
                wrapperAnswer.append(removeAnswer);
                $(this).before(wrapperAnswer);
            });
            removeQuestion.click(function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            wrapperQuestion.append(question);
            wrapperQuestion.append(removeQuestion);
            wrapperQuestion.append($('<div>').append(addAnswer));
            $(this).before(wrapperQuestion);
        });
    });
```

Hope this will help

New Updated Answer

```
        $('.survey').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var map = new Array();
            var q;
            var form = $('#surveyForm');
            $('div[name="question"]').each(function(){
                q = $(this).find('.question')[0].value;
                q = [];
                $(this).find('.answer').each(function(){
                    q.push($(this).val()+"");
                });
                map.push(q)
            });
            var data = form.serializeArray();
            data["questions"] = JSON.stringify(map);
            console.log(data["questions"])
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: data
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't name my question and answer on purpose because that way they dont get included in the submitted data (and thats what I want), otherwise I would need to delete them and then append my own data. So that would be just more work. I changed my form reference to id but that didn't change anything. I updated my question to make it a little clearer what exactly my problem is.

Comment: but accoroding to jquery doc you have to add name attribute
`The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name attribute.`
plz checkout the doc for more info `https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/`

Comment: You're right and I changed that and now my questions and answers have names again, still nothing has changed.

Comment: did you console the data ?
what does it print ? coz i am getting this 
[
{
name:"action",
value:"add"
},
{
name:"quest",
value:"question one"
},
{
name:"answr",
value:"answer one"
}
]

Comment: Yes and I'm getting the same, and if I don't stringify my map I get at the end of that "Questions" and then my arrays. And I presume my problem is that the map isn't serialized therefore can't be submitted